# div click event not working

Tags: jquery

I have this simple code that append a div inside the body,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='/libs/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function() {
                $('#show').click( function() {
                    $("<div id='fade'></div>").appendTo('body');
                    $('#fade').fadeIn('fast');
                });

                $('#fade').click( function() {
                    $('#fade').remove('fast');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="show" id="show"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
#fade {
    display: none;
    background: black;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

#window {
    width: 440px;
    height: 356px;
    background: white;
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:30%;
    margin:-70px 0 0 -245px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Appending my div#fade is working fine, but my click event on #fade isn't working. I looks simple but I didn't know why isn't working fine.

Comment: Because you are trying to bind the event handler **before** the element **exists**.

Comment: Working solution http://jsfiddle.net/ffK3u/  OR http://jsfiddle.net/ffK3u/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response, also my bad that forgot to remove 'fast' inside the parenthesis I just renamed thats why. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working solution at http://jsfiddle.net/ffK3u/1/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
                $('#show').click( function() {
                    $("<div id='fade'></div>").appendTo('body');
                    $('#fade').fadeIn('fast');
                });

                $(document).on("click","#fade", function() {
                    $('#fade').fadeOut("slow",function(){
                        $('#fade').remove();
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using jQuery 1.7 you can use `.on()` to delegate the click to the document level.

```
$(document).on('click', '#fade', function() {
    $('#fade').remove('fast');
});
```

Basically you cannot set a click handler for an element that doesn't yet exist, however you can delegate the click to a parent, in this instance `document`. When document receives the click it'll check to make sure it came from `#fade` and do whatever you need it to do.

This method is the newer and better version of `.live()`, of which you may or may not have seen used to bind events to elements that are dynamically inserted into the DOM.

For further reading, this technique relies on event bubbling and event delegation.

Answer (score 2):

***[THE DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/ePPVB/)***

**You don't need to create a new div every time**, just cache it in a local variable.

Using `.on` will work, but not necessary.

```
var fade = $("<div id='fade'></div>").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});

$('#show').click(function () {
    fade.appendTo('body').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) in jquery only accept `selector` as parameter

```
            $('#show').click( function() {
                $("<div id='fade'></div>").appendTo('body');
                $('#fade').fadeIn('fast');

                $('#fade').click( function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lsfw/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fade out, do this:

```
$('#fade').click( function() {
    $('#fade').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function() {
            alert($('#show'));
                $('#show').click( function() {
                    alert(0);//this code already execution,prove click event not problem.
                    $("<div id='fade'></div>").appendTo('body');//issue here 'body' replace document.body
                    $('#fade').fadeIn('fast');
                });

                $('#fade').click( function() {
                    $('#fade').remove('fast');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="show" id="show"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```